# How to transform a text file into a picture

Tags: command-line

If I have a plain text file, how can I convert it to an image file through the command line? (and preserve the layout of the ASCII art in it)

Comment: I would start looking for a automatic way to render text with a monospace font (gimp or LaTeX might be the way to go)

Comment: This is an ugly solution, but why don't just `cat` it and take a screenshot?

Comment: That would be too ugly, and a screenshot would include additional information, like the prompt.

Comment: If only the prompt is the problem, try this:
`clear && cat file`. But yes, it's ugly.

Comment: no that would still show my user name... And unless I find a way of making a screenshot through the command line, it won't be acceptable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115076/automate-conversion-of-text-to-png-or-another-file-format-with-transparency | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182850/converting-source-ascii-files-to-jpegs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use openoffice (libreoffice) to do it.

```
soffice --convert-to jpg "Textfile.doc"
```

it works with text files too.

Comment: That... is awesome! I had no idea OpenOffice could convert to JPG... or PNG, which I just tried; probably other formats as well. (Doesn't help that there's no mention or even hint of this in the `--help` output.) Only wrinkle, if the text is longer than a page, it looks like you only get the first page. (If there's a way to tell it to output other pages or multiple files, it's not immediately obvious to me. Passing `--outdir` makes no difference.) But for short bits of text, it works EXTREMELY well, and even auto-wraps. Nice!

Comment: This produces a fixed sized page with potentially tiny text on it if the text is small.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 Fixed-size page, true, but that's where ImageMagick's auto-cropping comes in handy again: `soffice --convert-to jpg ascii.txt && mogrify -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" -border 10 +repage ascii.jpg`

Comment: I don't want to change the meaning of your answer, but I highly suggest editing it to `--convert-to png` instead.  It's not only lossless (no ugly JPEG artifacts), but for something simple like text, the file size will probably be smaller for PNG than for even a moderate quality JPG.

Comment: Yeah, @mwfearnley is right, PNG is definitely a better choice. For the ASCII-art Tux we've been using as a sample in the answers here, the difference between JPG and PNG was 34K vs 19K ­— and that's _before_ I trimmed the margins. Once it was trimmed, the PNG is only 3.3K to the JPG's 30K... and the PNG is clearer, too.

Comment: Can we increase the font size?

Answer (score 39):

`imagemagick` is your friend here. Something similar to the following may help you:-

```
convert -size 360x360 xc:white -font "FreeMono" -pointsize 12 -fill black -draw @ascii.txt image.png
```

where `ascii.txt` is your ascii-art file:-

```
text 15,15 "                 .88888888:. 
                88888888.88888. 
              .8888888888888888. 
              888888888888888888 
              88' _`88'_  `88888 
              88 88 88 88  88888 
              88_88_::_88_:88888 
              88:::,::,:::::8888 
              88`:::::::::'`8888 
             .88  `::::'    8:88. 
            8888            `8:888. 
          .8888'             `888888. 
          .8888:..  .::.  ...:'8888888:. 
        .8888.'     :'     `'::`88:88888 
       .8888        '         `.888:8888. 
      888:8         .           888:88888 
    .888:88        .:           888:88888: 
    8888888.       ::           88:888888 
    `.::.888.      ::          .88888888 
   .::::::.888.    ::         :::`8888'.:. 
  ::::::::::.888   '         .:::::::::::: 
  ::::::::::::.8    '      .:8::::::::::::. 
 .::::::::::::::.        .:888::::::::::::: 
 :::::::::::::::88:.__..:88888:::::::::::' 
  `'.:::::::::::88888888888.88:::::::::' 
        `':::_:' -- '' -'-' `':_::::'`  
    "
```

with `text 15,15` added as the first line of text (the 15,15 is a positional offset).  Also, make sure that the actual text to be converted is enclosed in quotes.  Single or double quotes will do, but make sure they're not used as part of your ascii-art as it will confuse matters.

The font you choose should be a monospaced font, otherwise the text won't align.

This produces:-

[image]

Comment: Do you have a hint on how to get a list of valid font names? While Free Mono seems to be installed on my system, imagemagick does not recognize it.

Comment: @Raphael: You can get a list of currently-available fonts from any ImageMagick command (including convert) using the `-list` option. So e.g. `convert -list font` would show you all of the possible arguments to `-font`.

Comment: You could also install this program by using  `sudo yum install ImageMagick`.

Comment: @R.Ketkaew That command is valid for someone running Fedora 21 or lower, or some revisions of RHEL (not even sure if the latest is still using yum). On Fedora 22+ the install command is `sudo dnf install ImageMagick`, and on most other popular Linux distros it'll be some `sudo apt-get install ...` command. Regardless, the information above does indeed assume that ImageMagick is installed on the system in question.

Answer (score 21):

I find ImageMagick's `-annotate` operator to be a bit more convenient than the `-draw` method garethTheRed suggested, for the simple reason that it doesn't require modification of the input file. It's not as powerful as `-draw`, but for wholesale dumping of a text file's contents into an image it serves just fine.

```
convert -size 360x360 xc:white -font "FreeMono" -pointsize 12 -fill black \
-annotate +15+15 "@ascii.txt" image.png
```

will output a rendered version of the given file contents, but without having to modify your "ascii.txt" file to contain the `text 15x15` part of the `-draw` primitive.

#### Specifying Arguments

The argument to `-font` can be any supported font name, if FreeMono isn't available (or simply isn't desired). A list of the fonts available  to any ImageMagick command can be obtained using the `-list` operator, so `convert -list font` will display all of the possible arguments to `-font`.

The arguments to `-annotate` (how far to shift the rendered text from the edge of the canvas) consist of horizontal and vertical pixel offsets (respectively). The first offset (horizontal x-shift) can be any positive integer, but needn't be greater than a few pixels. The second offset (vertical y-shift) *must* be **at least** equal to the point size of the font chosen (the argument to `-pointsize`), because ImageMagick will place the *baseline* of the font at the given offset. So if you don't shift the font down at least `pointsize` pixels, the top of the first line will be cut off.

I recommend going over by several pixels at least, so if you're using `-pointsize 64` then you should pair that with something like `-annotate +15+80`. (There's no reason to increase the horizontal offset with larger font sizes, it has no relationship to the text dimensions.)

Needing to guess the necessary dimensions of the output image can also be tedious. I usually just pick excessive values, then take advantage of ImageMagick's `-trim` and `-border` to autocrop the result. The following command:

```
convert -size 1000x2000 xc:white -font "FreeMono" -pointsize 12 -fill black \
-annotate +15+15 "@ascii.txt" -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" -border 10 +repage image.png
```

will render into a 1000x2000 box, then trim off the excess white space except for a 10-pixel border all the way around the text. The `+repage` at the very end prevents the output PNG being created with an image offset, which would otherwise cause GIMP to pop up a dialog on load asking whether it should apply the offset.

(Obviously, 1000x2000 is excessive for small text files, and for longer ones at least the vertical dimension may need to be increased. It's simpler to overestimate, though, as the only cost is `convert` consuming slightly more CPU and memory while processing.)

### Preprocessing Input

If your text file isn't already formatted the way you need in order to render it (say, if it uses very long lines) then you may have to reformat it before handing it to `convert`. ImageMagick won't wrap the text, so each line of text will extend its full length horizontally. Fortunately, it's possible to run the file through any command-line formatters you'd like, then pipe the processed text into `convert` instead of reading directly from the file:

```
fmt < ascii.txt | convert -size 1000x2000 xc:white -font "DejaVu-Sans-Condensed" \
-pointsize 24 -fill black -annotate +15+30 "@-" -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" \
-border 10 +repage image.png
```

That'll render the contents of `ascii.txt` in 24-point DejaVu Sans Condensed, *after* it's been processed by the `fmt` command, which in its default mode of operation will reformat its input by word-wrapping to a width of 75 columns. (Unless there are long continuous strings longer than 75 characters, like URLs, in which case they'll extend over.)

Once `fmt` has reformatted the text, it'll be passed to `convert` which will then render the piped `fmt` output, same as if it was reading the file directly. (Specifying a filename of `-` is a fairly common UNIX shell shorthand for "read from standard input, instead of any named disk file", and ImageMagick's tools follow that convention.)

Comment: The y component of  `annotate` argument should be bigger than pointsize to be sure everything appears: `convert -size 1000x2000 xc:white -font "FreeMono" -pointsize 123 -fill black \
-annotate +0+123 "@ascii.txt" -trim -bordercolor "#FFF" -border 10 +repage image.png` where `123` is the desired size. Also, you can use `convert -list font` to find out which fonts are supported (`"FreeMono"` isn't universally supported).

Comment: @AlecJacobson That's a good point, about the Y value, since `-annotate` positions from the font baseline. `+15+15` is enough for 12-point, but larger fonts might not fit. I personally wouldn't set the X value to 0, _or_ the Y value to exactly the point size, though, because IM will antialias fonts by default. So I can't say for certain, but it feels like a gamble pressing the text right up against the edge of the bounding box. I figure better to leave a little extra on the top and left, since you're going to be automatically trimming it anyway. Two sides or four, no difference. IMHO.

Comment: I'll incorporate the baseline-positioning info, along with the font-list command (which was covered in the comments to gareth's answer, but it makes sense to have it here I agree), plus a piping trick I just experimentally discovered for the text file. Thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: ImageMagick 6.9.10 Ubuntu 19.04 failed with `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `@ascii.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3703.` with the tux without the ugly metadata. I wonder if there is a way to not hack policy files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 Hmm, good question. My IM7 install doesn't have any policies set in `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.txt` that interfere with any of these convert forms. Do you know what policy is blocking the convert, and why it's set? (Also, grasping at straws: Does the piped `fmt ...` form of the command work, by any chance? If so, you could just replace `fmt` with `cat`, and get the same result as the `@ascii.txt` version.)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 Oh, one more question: You specified "failed... with the tux without the ugly metadata". Does that mean that `convert` _succeeds_ when you use @garethTheRed's `-draw` form and insert the positioning commands into the `ascii.txt` file? It'd be pretty _bizarre_ if that's the case, seems to me, since I'm having trouble imagining what security concerns there would be with `-annotate` that wouldn't also apply to `-draw`, when working off the contents of an imported text file.

Comment: I hadn't even tried Gareth's answer because of the ugly metadata, but that did work now. My `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` contains `<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>` so I'm guessing that's the one. stdin also doesn't work, presumably because it also has the `@-` pattern in it. For the desperate, `"$(cat ascii.txt)"` works if it doesn't blow up CLI length.

Comment: Mmm, I see the [debian patch](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/imagemagick/blob/master/debian/patches/0007-Improve-policy-in-order-to-be-safer.patch) that adds that rule to the policy file. The comment justification above it reads, `<!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->`. 
Bit dubious, but whatever. **#WhyWeCantHaveNiceThings**

Comment: Works well for arbitrary texts, not just ascii art :-)

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution is to use `pango-view` provided by [Pango](https://www.pango.org/), a text rendering library used in GTK you likely already have installed:

```
pango-view --font=mono -qo image.png file
```

You can create [SVGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) too!

```
pango-view --font=mono -qo image.svg file
```

`pango-view` has many customization and layout option, consult its man page.