# /var/log/syslog as background image

Tags: bash, scripting, syslog, wallpaper

I like to have a text file (vor example /var/log/syslog) as a background image within years. So for example a script that automatically turns the syslog file into a jpg file and then sets it as background image (and deletes the old image). That for exmp. every 30 seconds

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS gnome

I really recommend to have a black background

EDIT: I know that I can turn a ASCII file into a jpeg file with this command:

```
soffice --convert-to jpg "Textfile.doc"
```

and I wrote a script that is doing the work, but I can't read the log files like I open a terminal, because it is extrmly zoomed and more than the half of the text isn't shown (decrease zoom can help showing the whole text and MORE LINES)

[How to transform a text file into a picture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138804/how-to-transform-a-text-file-into-a-picture)

france1@macubuntu:~/syslog-wallaper$ cat convert-to-jpg.sh; cat wallaper-changer.sh; cat run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r syslog.jpg
soffice --convert-to jpg "/var/log/syslog"
```

#####wallaper-changer

```
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:////home/france1/syslog-wallaper/syslog.jpg
```

##run-file

```
!/bin/bash

while [ 1 == 1 ] do
    bash ./convert-to-jpg.sh
    bash ./wallaper-changer.sh
    sleep 30 done
```

that's it

Oh and:
I would like to have a picture, black with white text

Comment: I found a ways to convert and one way to set wallaper, but it's not black background and not perfect at all

Comment: You need to spend some time and make your question clearer, otherwise you will get flooded with downvotes and have your question deleted.

Comment: It looks like your question is how to turn the contents of a text file like `syslog` into an image with a black background and white text.

Comment: You might want to look at conky and its `tail` command.

Comment: I added my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the program "root-tail".  It is available in Debian Linux, and I think others.  Its current home page is http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/root-tail.html

It does a "`tail`" on a file, or several, and displays it on the root window.  It can do so on top of a background image or background color.  It keeps the text up to date.